# Wrong data type OleDB Create Table

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I m using the following function to create an access table:

```
        public static void createtable(string path, string tablename, string[] columnnames)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionstring = creadteconnectionstring(path);
            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            string columnam = "[" + columnnames[0] + "] Text";

            for (int i = 1; i < columnnames.Length; i++)
            {
                    columnam = columnam + ", [" + columnnames[i] + "] Text";
            }

            myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + tablename + "](" + columnam + ")";
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Access table " + tablename + " created.");
        }
        catch 
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Access table " + tablename + " already exists.");
                return;


        }


    }
```

However if I open the access table in MS access the data type is Memo, not Text. Other data types [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320435) specified by MS dont seem to work at all.

Any ideas are welcome? Thanks!

Comment: I think you use `VARCHAR(50)` or `NVARCHAR(50)` instead of `TEXT`.  The number is the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Access DDL TEXT data type behaves differently depending on the context where you execute your statement.

From DAO in Access, this creates *bar* as a text field.  But from ADO in Access, *bar* will be memo type.

```
CREATE TABLE tblFoo (bar TEXT)
```

Executing that statement from an OleDb connection produces the same result as with ADO in Access.

If you want *bar* to be an actual text field, include a field length <= 255.

```
CREATE TABLE tblFoo (bar TEXT(255))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about doubles? Number: Double[15]

Comment: Use `DOUBLE` in your DDL for double type.  But I don't think the Access db engine accepts a length argument for double.  For other data types, refer to the *DDL (Queries)* column at http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html